# Kfold cross validation in sklearn gives different folds each time

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, train-test-split

I want to implement KFold cross validation on my model. Since I want to share my results with others, I want to have fixed results each time. I am using an xgboost model as my classification model. However, each time I run my code, my performance metrics give different results each time and I am confused because I set the `shuffle` parameter to `False`. Also, I am unsure what the `random_state` parameter does (I read the documentation), but regardless I tried setting that to a fixed number with shuffle=False, and that did not help.

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle = False)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
    xgb = XGBClassifier(max_depth = 4)
    ...fit, predict, and compute performance metrics
```

Comment: When passing a number in the parameter`random_state` you're fixing the seed for the internal random number generator. In the future if you set it to the same number again, the sequence of random numbers generated will be always the same. In this way you can guarantee the reprocibility of your results, just like how you wants.

Comment: Thanks! I used both shuffle = False and the random state. I should have only used random state.

Comment: Nice! I will put that comment as an answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

When passing a number in the parameter `random_state` you're fixing the seed for the internal random number generator. In the future if you set it to the same number again, the sequence of random numbers generated will always be the same. In this way you can guarantee the reproducibility of your results, just like how you wants.

Comment: Yeah, I resolved the issue but I initially set shuffle = False and the combo of that with random_state did not work.

Comment: Attention that `random_state` does not guarantee reproducibility between differing numpy and sklearn versions or differing operating systems.